# Visualforce email template not resolving recipient and relatedTo at runtime (WhoID, WhatID)

Tags: visualforce, email, email-template, process-builder

We are having several VF templates that are used in an email alert in a Process.

When we trigger the Process from Apex, then the Process *is* run, but the email template is not merged properly (even though it is sent to the proper email address): the recipient and the relatedTo are not resolved, so all merge tags show empty. Using workflows instead of a Process yields the same negative result.

My observations:

- The templates merge fine when we test them manually (i.e. without
  triggering the Process, but do a test-and-verify)
- The templates merge
  fine when we trigger the Process through the UI (i.e. we edit a
  record via the UI, the Process runs)
- The templates DO NOT merge when
  we trigger the Process/Workflow from Apex code (i.e. we edit the record via
  Apex)

​Can anybody confirm this and/or share a solution? Thanks!

For reference, this is the simplest email template I could produce:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="TEST" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Check__c">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        Hey {!relatedTo.Guest__r.FirstName}
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Then we have an email alert that is based on this email template, and that sends the email to `Related Contact: Guest`.

Then either a Workflow or a Process sends an email alert, from a `Check__c` record that has `Check__r.Guest__c` definitely filled in. The email *is* sent to the proper email address.

Yet, what is generated is "Hey " and not "Hey Frank" (or any other name).

Comment: So, what you're saying is this is an issue you're having with Process builder? If it's not picking up the WhoID, how is it managing to get the proper email address, or does that only happen when the WhoID is not the recipient? If that's the case, I think you may need to post more details about the triggering object and the related objects.

Comment: @crmprogdev Yes, it's only happening via the Process Builder. It *does* find the proper email address, but it does not provide the proper merge tags to the Email Template. Thus, the email template renders broken, but the mail *is* sent to the proper WhoID. Any clue? Could you try to reproduce?

Comment: Again, we need to know more in order to reproduce. What object, what fields, what conditions, etc. Can you post your template code and conditions for it being fired by PB?

Comment: @crmprogdev you're right. Sorry for that. I updated the question with a simple example.

Comment: When you say you edit the record via Apex, what kind of Apex are you running? Process Builder may fire before the edit will be committed to the database.

Comment: @crmprogdev in a VF Controller. But Processes and Workflows should only fire *after* code is committed, if I'm right.

Comment: No, afraid not. See Order of Execution. Load Record, Validation Rules, Before Triggers, Save without Commit, After Triggers, Assignment Rules, Workflow, Rerun Triggers, PB, Esc Rules, Roll-ups, etc, finally Commits to Database, last thing is to send post commit actions like emails.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. But the emails should still contain the new values. Anyway, it doesn't matter in our case, because in Apex we only set a simple flag 'SendEmail' which is then picked up by the Workflow/Process. All other information, for example the Check__r.Guest__r.Name is already there. So the email template should be able to find it. Also, if I trigger the same flag through the UI, it *does* work.

Comment: I agree with you with one caveat. Are you using the same controller on the same object in your VF Page as you are in the UI when you perform the DML? If not, PB won't have the same context to be able to access those related objects. I'd venture to say that the issue is with the design of your controller. DML is DML. If you test by upserting records, your template should also work (bypasses UI).

Comment: @crmprogdev I found it! The issue was that we were running the Apex from a Force.com Site, and the profile missed the Field Level Security for the Guest__r lookup field :-( Thanks for thinking along, and sorry for this being so obvious! Have a good weekend.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted and that I could help you think it through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! The issue was that we were running the Apex from a Force.com Site, and the profile missed the Field Level Security for the Guest__r lookup field.

Comment: in addition all `{!recipient.<field_name>}` merge fields don't work in vf email templates when sent by workflow, listed as a known issue - no fix https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SdBfAAK